# How to implement progress bar for onback() in android webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, progress-bar

I have a webview app where progress bar shows up till page gets loaded up when navigating from one page to another but not shows up when back button pressed. 
The page is getting loaded from history stack when back button pressed. Any solution to implement progressbar for on back().

Comment: are you loading your webpage in onCreate() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**`onBackPressed()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

- Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

Than check in `onBackPressed()` that `webView` can go to previous page using [**`WebView.canGoBack()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack())

-`webView.canGoBack()` Gets whether this WebView has a back history item.

> If yes than display **`progressBar`** again
>   else call `super.onBackPressed();`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod?tab=profile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            progressBar.setProgress(1);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}
```

> Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```